# How do i display this messagebox if all the textboxes is completed succesfully

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner in c# and i wrote myself a program. It checks if all the textboxes is filled correctly then it should display messagebox when save button is pressed but if all the textboxes isn't correct it shouldn't display it

[image: My windows form and how i want it to be.]

This is the messagebox code:

```
    if (MessageBox.Show("Data is being saved", "Data saving", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox3.Text = "";
        textBox4.Text = "";
    }
```

This is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _5_prakt
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Regex regex1 = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
            Regex dat = new Regex("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])([0-9]{2})[-]([0-9]{5})$");
            Regex epasts = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
            if (!regex1.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
            {
                label5.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label5.Text = "Incorrectly entered name!";
            }
            else
            {
                label5.Text = "";
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                label5.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label5.Text = "Name wasn't entered!";
            }

            if (!regex1.IsMatch(textBox2.Text))
            {
                label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label6.Text = "Surname entered incorrectly!";
            }
            else
            {
                label6.Text = "";
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
            {
                label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label6.Text = "No surname!";
            }

            if (!dat.IsMatch(textBox3.Text))
            {
                label7.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label7.Text = "Incorrect code!";
            }
            else
            {
                label7.Text = "";
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text))
            {
                label7.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label7.Text = "Not entered!";
            }

            if (!epasts.IsMatch(textBox4.Text))
            {
                label8.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label8.Text = "Incorrectly entered email!";
            }
            else
            {
                label8.Text = "";
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text))
            {
                label8.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                label8.Text = "Email not entered!";
            }

            if (MessageBox.Show("Data is being saved", "Data saving", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "";
                textBox2.Text = "";
                textBox3.Text = "";
                textBox4.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not at all clear - that code doesnt save anything, it just clears the text controls.

Comment: Add validation check for all text boxes and display the messagebox

Comment: There is no save code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not exactly clear what you are trying to do - but if I understand correctly - you want to keep track of whether there is an error and only do the save if no errors? You can do this with a boolean that will indicate if any errors. Also - your MessageBox only has the Ok button - so it doesn't make sense with an if statement. Did you mean Ok Cancel?

Please see comments in the modified code below:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Regex regex1 = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
        Regex dat = new Regex("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])([0-9]{2})[-]([0-9]{5})$");
        Regex epasts = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");

        // Use a boolean to determine whether there is an error
        var valid = true;

        if (!regex1.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
        {
            valid = false;
            label5.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label5.Text = "Incorrectly entered name!";
        }
        else
        {
            label5.Text = "";
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
        {
            valid = false;
            label5.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label5.Text = "Name wasn't entered!";
        }

        if (!regex1.IsMatch(textBox2.Text))
        {
            valid = false;
            label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label6.Text = "Surname entered incorrectly!";
        }
        else
        {
            label6.Text = "";
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
        {
            valid = false;
            label6.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label6.Text = "No surname!";
        }

        if (!dat.IsMatch(textBox3.Text))
        {
            valid = false;
            label7.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label7.Text = "Incorrect code!";
        }
        else
        {
            label7.Text = "";
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text))
        {
            valid = false;
            label7.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label7.Text = "Not entered!";
        }

        if (!epasts.IsMatch(textBox4.Text))
        {
            valid = false;
            label8.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label8.Text = "Incorrectly entered email!";
        }
        else
        {
            label8.Text = "";
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text))
        {
            valid = false;
            label8.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label8.Text = "Email not entered!";
        }

        // Now you can check if there is an error 
        if (valid)
        {

            // This doesn't make any sense - because the user can ONLY click ok 
            //if (MessageBox.Show("Data is being saved", "Data saving", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK)
            // I think you maybe meant something like this? 
            if (MessageBox.Show("Data is being saved", "Data saving", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // And here - I'm assuming you would save the data somewhere and then clear the textboxes? 
                textBox1.Text = "";
                textBox2.Text = "";
                textBox3.Text = "";
                textBox4.Text = "";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please correct the errors and try again");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At the start of your method put this:

```
bool valid = true;
```

At each `if` where you find that you have an input error put this:

```
valid = false;
```

Then at the end of the method put this:

```
if (valid && MessageBox.Show("Data is being saved", "Data saving", MessageBoxButtons.OK) == DialogResult.OK)
{
    textBox1.Text = "";
    textBox2.Text = "";
    textBox3.Text = "";
    textBox4.Text = "";
}
```